# commander.js: passing isDefault option for command with action()

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

As per the [commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/) readme, I can specify the default command thus:

```
var program = ...;

program
  ...
  .command('list', 'list packages installed', {isDefault: true})
  .parse(process.argv);
```

In my application, I'm using the `.command()` without the description parameter, for using `.action()`. I tried passing the second param `null` and the third option with the `isDefault:true`. But it does not seem to work:

```
program.command('help', null, {isDefault:true})
  .description('display help information.')
  .action(function(){
    program.outputHelp();
  });
```

How do I pass `isDefault:true` to a command with `.action()`?

Comment: No support [on reporting to developers](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/issues/469). No support in SO. Started my own implementation: [WizTools.org Cli Parse](https://github.com/wiztools/wiz-cliparse).

Answer (score 1):

according to the [documentation](https://github.com/tj/commander.js):

> When .command() is invoked with a description argument, no .action(callback) should be called to handle sub-commands, otherwise there will be an error.

I believe this means that you will need to find a workaround, such as writing a separate subcommand.